# Wrong sample space in simulation

Tags: r

In Twitter, I came across a puzzle that goes like this:

*There are ten coins, each blank on one side and numbered on the other side with numbers 1 through 10. All ten coins are tossed and the sum of the numbers landing face up is calculated. What is the probability that this sum is at least 45?*

I wanted to build a simulation that reproduces the analytical solution, which is 43/1024 with some reasonably small error of course

My first attempt:

```
# Create a list of all possible values
values <- c(1:10, rep(0,10))

# Number of trials
nt <- 5e5

# Container vector to store the results
output <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = nt)

# set seed for reproducible result
ns <- 42

# Loop
for (i in 1:nt) {
  set.seed(ns)
  temp <- sample(x = values, size = 10, replace = F)
  output[i] <- sum(temp)
  ns <- ns + 1
}

length(output[output > 44]) / nt


# [1] 0.013736
```

Second attempt:

```
rm(list = ls())

values <- 1:10
nt <- 5e5
output <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = nt)
ns <- 42

for (i in 1:nt) {
  set.seed(ns)
  temp <- sample(x = c(0,1), size = 10, replace = T)
  output[i] <- sum(temp * values)
  ns <- ns + 1
}

length(output[output > 44]) / nt

# [1] 0.042038

# Find the fraction (X / 1024) which trows minimal error

sim.res <- length(output[output > 44]) / nt
fractions <- (1:2^10)/2^10
difference <- abs(sim.res - fractions)
which(difference == min(difference))

# [1] 43
```

Obviously, the only difference between these two approaches is the construction of the sample space for the simulation. I am staring at the code and can not figure out why number 1 is wrong. They should perform identicaly for all I know.

Comment: note that setting the seed just once ahead of your loop is totally sufficient and more appropriate

Comment: That will create the exact same sample 5e5 times. Just tried it out. Got half a million "16".

Comment: Creating the exact same sample 5e5 times would actually require you re-setting the seed **inside** the loop to the same value every time (e.g. if you had just removed the `ns <- ns + 1`)

Comment: Yes, you are right

Answer (score 0):

Your first (incorrect) simulation simply selects 10 numbers without replacement from the vector:

```r
c(1:10, rep(0, 10))
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

*(An incorrect calculation of the probability of getting 10 `0` was deleted.)*

Let's say the first of your 10 selections is not a `0`. Maybe it comes up as `7`. That means the probability of the second selection being `0` is now 10/19.

But in the actual scenario as described it doesn't matter if the 0-7 labelled coin comes up as 7, the probability of any other coin coming up as 0 is still 1/2, because the coin outcomes are independent.

By the way, the `replicate` function is almost built for simulation. Here's the `R` way to write this simulation:

```r
nt <- 1e5
sims <- replicate(nt, sample(0:1, 10, repl=TRUE)*(1:10))
```

The probability in question is then:

```r
p_gte_45 <- mean(apply(sims, 2, function(x) sum(x) >= 45))
```

Comment: there's something wrong with your 0.1761971 for 10 zeros - unless I misunderstand

Comment: Yes, it's `prod((10:1)/(20:11)`, so I'll delete that part.

Comment: @ngm Excellent point. I obviously violated the independence principle. As for "replicate()" - I use it all the time, but really don't know how to combine it with set.seed() when reproducibility is needed